# Creating bars that are one day width with correct mapping on x-axis in Flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I am creating a graph using Flot. The data are prices on a specific day that are displayed using a bar chart. It currently looks like this:
[image]

On the above image, you can also see my problem: the x-axis doesn't correspond with the x-axis in the tooltip. I want the axis to map correctly, and also that the gray bars correspond with the weekends. Currently, 10 and 11 October are drawn in the weekend bar, while 11 and 12 October is the real weekend. The data is retrieved using AJAX.

The code I now have is:

```
var options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: '%e %b',
        minTickSize: [1, "day"],
        autoscaleMargin: 0.02
    },
    selection: {
        mode: "x"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        markings: weekendAreas
    },
    bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 86400000 // 1 day in seconds
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%s on %x: &euro; %y.2",
        shifts: {
            x: -60,
            y: 25
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    },
    series: {
        stack: true
    }
};

$.getJSON(graphOptions.route, function (data) {
    options['xaxis']['min'] = data.from;
    options['xaxis']['max'] = data.to;
    var plot = $.plot("#flot-cost-chart", data.data, options);
}).fail(function (e) {
    alert('An error occured');
});
```

The `graphOptions.route` is the URL that is supplied by my web page. The data retrieved looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "label": "Test 1",
        "data": [
            [
                1413064800000,
                173.1
            ],
            [
                1413583200000,
                104
            ],
            [
                1412978400000,
                100
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Test 3",
        "data": [
            [
                1413064800000,
                112
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "Test 2",
        "data": [
            [
                1413064800000,
                130
            ],
            [
                1413151200000,
                112
            ]
        ]
    }
],
"to": 1414796400000,
"from": 1412114400000
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. Alignment of the bars: Your bars are left aligned. Try `align: center` in your bar options.
2. The weekend bar is on 11 October and 12 October (see above).
3. Your Test 2 - 112 value is on 13 October midnight **UTC** which seems correct in the graph. The tooltip can show another date when your are in another timezone.

Comment: Thanks! Point 1 worked perfectly. You are correct for point 2, I was confused by the timezones as pointed out in point 3, I now set the time to be at 12:00 pm that day, so it is correct for me (Europe/Amsterdam). Luckily I don't have to deal with other timezones :)